# How to ensure Excel field formulas are copied all the way down to a larger dataset

Tags: excel, excel-formula, copy, copy-paste, large-data

I have copied two different files to do a comparison. The first columns range from A-N. The second column range to compare with the first column range is P-AC. The O column is where my formula is and checks an exact comparison of fields.  The following is my formula in the first row of O1:

> =if(and(a1<>p1, b1<>q1, c1<>r1, d1<>s1, e1<>t1, f1<>u1, g1<>v1, h1<>w1, i1<>x1, j1<>y1, k1<>z1, l1<>aa1, m1<>ab1, n1<>ac1),
> "FAIL", "PASS")

The above formula is yielding incorrect results when I attempt to drag copy the formula down to the last row.

How do ensure the formula is incrementally copied all the way down?

I'm open to other suggestions on how to accomplish this in a more efficient manner.

**EDIT TO INCLUDED SCREENSHOT OF EXPECTED VALUES:**

Rows A3-N3 (includes column header):
[image]

Rows P3-AC3 (includes column header):
[image]

Rows 01-O3 (column header should be "PASS" as is because all the column headers match from both documents):

[image]

To reiterate, my result column in O for the screenshots shown should be "PASS" as they are, but when I copy the formula all the way down it starts to get funky.  They are showing "PASS" when should be showing "FAIL".

Comment: Please show a screenshot of the incorrect results, and what the expected result is.

Comment: @BigBen Edited to show screenshots.

Comment: You will only get `FAIL` if *all* of the columns are not identical. Change the `AND` to `OR` if you want `FAIL` if *any* of the columns don't match.

Comment: @BigBen No, Please read the formula which starts at Row 1. The column header shows PASS bc I check to ensure all column headers are the same as well. I'm checking all columns to make sure they match within the documents.

Comment: @BigBen I'm checking for all columns between the docs. They should all be the same and I know that some aren't which is what I'm checking for. It's a large document and this is to streamline the analysis.

Comment: To whomever voted to close, this question meets all requirements of a good question and specifically stated all relevant tags. If you can't answer then move on.

Comment: That was me (you didn't have a [reprex] until you added the screenshots).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm checking for all columns between the docs. They should all be the same and I know that some aren't which is what I'm checking for.

Your logic is off. Use:

```
=if(and(a1=p1, b1=q1, c1=r1, d1=s1, e1=t1, f1=u1, g1=v1, h1=w1, i1=x1, j1=y1, k1=z1, l1=aa1, m1=ab1, n1=ac1), "PASS", "FAIL")
```

or

```
=if(or(a1<>p1, b1<>q1, c1<>r1, d1<>s1, e1<>t1, f1<>u1, g1<>v1, h1<>w1, i1<>x1, j1<>y1, k1<>z1, l1<>aa1, m1<>ab1, n1<>ac1), "FAIL", "PASS")
```

If you try to use `AND` instead of `OR` in the second formula, then the only way you'll get `"FAIL"` is if *every single condition* is `TRUE`, i.e. `a1` must be different than `p1`, `b1` must be different than `q1`, and so on.